# Anyone ever tried Canada Immigration Express?

Tags: visa, immigration, resident-permit, canada, express-entry

I'm trying to migrate to Canada, and I was sent a link to a private agency called **Canada Immigration Express**, from a mate who got it from an ad, I registered and paid 20$.

Finally they called me two weeks later telling me I have a good chance and that they are taking care of my application, but before we proceed I would like to know if they are in anyway trustworthy, and if that is not answered then how can I know if they are ?

Comment: Immigration specialists should be registered. You can check that [here](https://iccrc-crcic.ca/) although they state that they're having IT problems right now. CIE's website says that they subcontract registered specialists so there's an extra level of costs right there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The company you found has this footer

> The CanadaImmigrationExpress.com website is owned and operated by the EU Company, Global Worldwide Online Marketing Limited, Registration Number 10816710, Lynton House, 7-12 Tavistock Square, WC1H 9BQ, London, UK, which is a private international company that is not related to Canada’s government or the ICCRC and is not a member or agent of the ICCRC. Copyright © 2020 All rights reserved. Reproduction in whole or in part without permission is prohibited.

Monty Python had a relevant song, we just need to replace one letter in it, goes like this:

Lovely Scam! Wonderful Scam!
Lovely Scam! Wonderful Scam
Sca-a-a-a-a-a-a-am
Sca-a-a-a-a-a-a-am
Sca-a-a-a-a-a-a-am
Sca-a-a-a-a-a-a-am
Lovely Scam! (Lovely Scam!)
Lovely Scam! (Lovely Scam!)
Lovely Scam!
Scam, Scam, Scam, Scam!

It's a marketing agency in the European Union which is not a ICCRC agent, what do you *think* they are capable of doing?

An overwhelming majority of people find the Express Entry online system very straightforward which they can manage by themselves. Only people with very complicated histories might need the help of a Regulated Canadian Immigration Consultant. The list is at https://iccrc-crcic.ca/find-a-professional-frame/

PS: This is the official [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBcY3W5WgNU) link to Monty Python's aforementioned song.